# Can't Try nor Install Ubuntu on Lenovo ideapad miix 310

Tags: boot, usb, lubuntu, lenovo, ideapad

I've just purchased a Lenovo ideapad miix 310 and my intention was to install Lubuntu but in the very first page after booting, when I click either to try or to install Lubuntu (same problem with Xubuntu and Ubuntu) I get a black screen. It remains black screen until I force the shut down with the button.

Secure boot disabled;
Downloaded the 64 bit version;
Iso image checked with md5sum;
Tried with two different USB drives;
Tried with Unetbootin from Mac and Rufus from Windows;

Same problem.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a USB flash stick you could try the linux live installer program - [linux live](https://www.linuxliveusb.com/). Some USB sticks aren't bootable I'm afraid so you might want to try a different one - it has to be formatted in FAT32 as well.

Comment: Thank you, I tried but it doesn't work. Same problem: black screen after choosing "try linux" or "install linux" immediately after booting. Linux live formatted my USB stick in FAT32.

Comment: Try a different stick maybe? If I recall rightly the BIOS needs to pick it up as USB FDD rather than HDD as well - you might have to change the boot preferences

Comment: Also there's a boot compatibility test  here: (https://www.pendrivelinux.com/testing-your-system-for-usb-boot-compatibility/). The Sandisk Extreme Pro is recommended by this site.

Answer (score 0):

try using rEFInd if booting a Live-USB with Grub does not work.  Also, check out Linuxium's blog for the latest on Linux distro for Atom Cherry-Trail devices. I've heard Kernel 4.12-rc2 is improved for CT and the forthcoming Ubuntu 17.10 will likely work fairly well out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Installed lubuntu 17 on lenovo ideapad miix310. The wifi works fine and the sound and touch. Bluetooth doesnt work and brightness controller.

I used rufus tool to put the image on usb stick. Gpt partition for uefi option on rufus tool.

U should disable the secure boot option in the bios ootions of the tablet.

To enter boot menu press the power button and the volume up button.

Note that one of the usb sticks didnt work. So u should be sure that the usb stick boots normally and fine by trying it on other computers

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to use Ubuntu 18.04 with the following fixes:

1. Fix for orientation of the display (iio-sensor-proxy udev config)
2. Fix for proper order of kernel modules load (pwm_lpss before i915)
3. Fix for early boot framebuffer rotation to landscape (grub)
   Available [here on GitHub](https://github.com/astrofimov/miix_310)

Installation done using flash drive.

Update: to start installation without black screen please press e button when you have grub menu on the screen and append linux image line with acpi_backlight=vender in this case even if display driver cannot join backlight control you backlight will stay turned on.

Comment: Please can you add the details of how to actually do these fixes? I consider myself somewhat pre-intermediatish in my Linux knowledge but I have no clue how to ensure one module gets loaded before another (wow, i915 is modular?!). Beginners are probably reading this answer and thinking wow, how do I do that?

Comment: This changes shall be just put in the etc folder to apply fixes in corresponding parts of the system. One more fix I've tested yesterday and it is for pulseaudio configuration. For some reason audio controls in tray are not active. Hope to update my description tomorrow.